# Как сохранить текст в UITextField?(Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

Заходишь в окно ввода данных заполняешь `textField`, но когда выходишь, данные пропадают, как их сохранить? Хочу, чтобы при выходе из этого окна, информация сохранялась:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: При выходе или при нажатии кнопки "Сохранить"?

Comment: При нажатии на сохранить, чтобы он сохранялся и когда выходишь и заходишь заново, чтобы он был там

Answer (score 2):

Есть несколько вариантов для решения вашей задачи.

I ) Использовать хранилище UserDefaults.
Простой пример кода:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // создаем хранилище UserDefaults:
    let userDef = UserDefaults.standard

    // аутлеты двух текстовых полей:
    @IBOutlet weak var text1: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var text2: UITextField!

    //кнопка для записи сохранения в UserDefaults введенных в текстовые поля значений:
    @IBAction func saveButton(_ sender: Any) {
        userDef.setValue(text1.text, forKey: "t1")
        userDef.setValue(text2.text, forKey: "t2")  
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //при запуске приложения значения для текстовых полей берутся из UserDefaults:
        text1.text = userDef.string(forKey: "t1")
        text2.text = userDef.string(forKey: "t2")
    }
}
```

II ) Использовать Core Data - это не просто и не быстро :)
Нужно долго тщательно изучать и реализовывать, в сети есть много мануалов и видео на эту тему. Core Data используют, если данных для хранения много.

III ) Использовать Realm - попроще и посовременнее (по мнению некоторых), но тоже нужно изучать...
Realm используют, если данных для хранения много.

Answer (score 1):

Именно для этого Вам можно использовать UserDefaults, так как данные небольшие. 
Во методе viewDidLoad извлекайте данные из UserDefaults и вставляйте их в текстовые поля. Это чтобы при открытии экрана они появлялись в полях.
А для сохранения данных, в @IBAction вашей кнопки "Сохранить" добавьте сохранение содержимого каждого поля в соотвествующий ему, текстовой UserDefaults.

Comment: Я пытался дерезе UserDefaults.standard работает 1 раз и когда я перезапускаю приложение он говорил о нахождении nil

Comment: Если можно добавьте в ваш вопрос кусочки кода с UserDefaults. Может что-то делаете не так.

Comment: добавлю как скрин к вопросу, а то в ответ на комментарий все в одной строке

Comment: это только для одного поля

Comment: Попробуйте поместить ваш код с if let text.... не во viewDidLoad, а в метод viewDidAppear.

Comment: разобрался, там оказался один класс для двух вью контроллеров

Comment: но не понял как передать данные после нажатия кнопки сохранить из TextField в UIButton, который на предыдущем контроллере